# How to restore backup created with kup-backup on fresh install of Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, backup, kde-apps

I took a backup of my laptop's home folder using `kup-backup` on an external hard drive. Then, I  did a clean format of my laptop's hard disk (please don't ask why) and installed `Kubuntu 20.04`.

The steps for taking backup were very straight forward. But I don't find any instruction on restoring a backup.

Can anyone help me or point to a resource with this information?
Thanks in advance!